# Multiple Left Join Giving Sum as Double

Tags: sql, mysql

I have my query like this

```
SELECT c.dates, SUM( CASE WHEN r.r_type = 0 THEN r.r_amount ELSE 0 END) AS extra_in,
SUM( CASE WHEN r.r_type = 1 THEN r.r_amount ELSE 0 END) AS extra_out 
FROM tbl_calendar as c 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_orders` AS o ON c.dates = DATE(o.order_complete_time) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_revenue AS r ON r.r_date = c.dates 
WHERE MONTH( c.dates) = 10 AND YEAR(c.dates ) = 2023 AND c.dates<= '2023-10-18' GROUP BY c.dates ORDER BY c.dates DESC
```

with above query, extra_in or extra_out giving me SUM double. If I have value 5 in table its giving me 10 and so on. If I remove one LEFT JOIN called tbl_orders, its giving me proper result.

[image]

I am not getting whats the wrong with my query. Let me know if someone here can help me for the same

Thanks!

Comment: What data types are o.order_complete_time and c.dates?

Comment: Try narrowing it down to one slice that you think is wrong and then expand on that. I bet you have multiple record in tbl_orders with a date that matches tbl_revenue., and since you have a group by on date you are pulling the same record twice, one for each order that falls on a matched date, creating doubles or triples.

Comment: Please put much more effort in your question! Pasting a screenshot and complaining the query is incorrect is not enough. Should people guess what data is in which table? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is due to one of the left joins, if it's `tbl_orders`, or `tbl_revenue` I can't say.

Let me explain why this is probably the issue - So you join `tbl_calender`, with `tbl_orders` based on date. Now, if there are multiple orders for a single date, each date from `tbl_calender` will be matched with every corresponding order from `tbl_orders` for that date.

Let's say your `tbl_calender` looks like this.

| dates |
| --- |
| 2023-10-01 |
| 2023-10-02 |

and `tbl_orders` look like this.

| order_id | order_complete_time | order_detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 10:00:00 | Order A |
| 2 | 2023-10-01 15:30:00 | Order B |

Now, when you perform a `LEFT JOIN` of `tbl_calendar` with `tbl_orders` based on the date:

```
SELECT c.dates, o.order_detail 
FROM tbl_calendar as c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_orders AS o ON c.dates = DATE(o.order_complete_time)
```

you get this

| dates | order_detail |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | Order A |
| 2023-10-01 | Order B |
| 2023-10-02 | NULL |

For the date `2023-10-01` in tbl_calendar, there are two matching rows in `tbl_orders` (Order A and Order B). So, the result of the join includes two rows for 2023-10-01, one for each order.

This result is correct, based on the query. The "duplication" arises due to multiple matching rows in the joined table for the given date. If you later join this result with another table that has multiple rows for the same date, you'll end up with several rows per date, and this is probably what is resulting in your "double sum".

I would suggest not joining on date on every join condition, maybe there is an `order_id` column?